# function to prove if file exists

Tags: php, foreach

Here is my script:

```
$imagesPerLine = array(1=>2, 2=>3); $default = 4;
$lines = array(1, 2, 3);
$html="";
foreach ($lines as $line) {
if (!isset($imagesPerLine[$line])) {
  $imagesPerLine[$line] = $default;
}
$html.= "<tr>\n";
for ($i = 1; $i <= $imagesPerLine[$line]; $i++) {
  $html.=sprintf("<td>%s</td>\n",any_function());
}
$html.="</tr>\n";
}
echo $html;
```

At this moment it looks like it should, here:

```
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

Now, in every "td-tag" I want my function `any_function()` to prove if one of three files exists.

What I did:

```
function any_function($transactionId)
{
$states = array('schwarz', 'rot', 'blau');

$path = '';

foreach ($states as $state) {
  $testPath = sprintf('transactions/Ordner%s/%s.png', $transactionId, $state);

    if (file_exists($testPath)) {
      $path = $testPath;
      echo $path;
      break;
    }
}
return $path;
}

$transactionIds = range(1,9);

foreach ($transactionIds as $transactionId) :

if (($transactionId % $imagesPerLine) == 1)

$path = any_function($transactionId);

$imageHtml = ('' !== $path)
    ? '<img src="' . $path . '" />'
    : '<img name="nummer.' . $transactionId . '" src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" />' ;

echo $imageHtml;


endforeach;
```

But it doesn't make sense now, so that's why I am asking you.

Important: `$transactionId` should be +1 every time it's displayed.

Can anyone help me with configuring my script?

Comment: What is exactly the question? Does the problem is in the testing of the existence of the file?

Comment: yes exactly this is the problem, i also think my function is to long..i just want to test if a file exists.if it does, display $a.if it doesnt, display $b.

Comment: OK did you have an error message to include? what is happennign at the moment when you run it

Comment: still displayes the "td-tags" only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$html.=sprintf("<td>%s</td>\n",any_function());
```

means your taking the return value of any_function and insert that in your string, which later will be echoed.

But

```
if (file_exists($testPath)) {
      $path = $testPath;
      echo $path;
      break;
    }
```

already echoes something ($path) which obviously will corrupt your output. Delete that echo line. same in the other function.